# Logging storage with web backend

Tags: python, logging, go

We need to store our logs from some services, each log has its level, namespace (maybe dotted namespace), tags (as a list), timestamp (when the log created) and its content (as a text).

We also need a web backend with ability to show/search/filter the log with its level, namespace, tag.

Is there an open-source system for that? I prefer Go or Python language. If not, what is the best solution for us?

*I do not know is this question legal or not for stackoverflow. I am just asking about a open-source solution.*

Thank you for reading this,

Comment: Python has a logging library, but if you already have the logs and just need to store them, what did you have in mind specifically?

Comment: Our services are written in some languages (PHP, Python, ...). Our need is not only store python's log but also store other logs like user's activity, product's information changing, api request/response log, ... etc. That's why we need namespace and tagging.

Comment: Have you looked at [logstash](http://logstash.net/)?

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/

Comment: Thank you, we will take try those solutions. However, for the first look, we are aware about elasticsearch's memory consumption.

Comment: @Tarzan where I work we're using Kibana for a very large volume of logs and it works great.  Logs are aggregated using Scribe and then pushed to Kibana for indexing. Works like a charm. BTW a commercial solution to look at would be Splunk, but personally I don't like it so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion, i will analytic some opensource system for log that i know:

1. logstash : you need kibana or any the same for web interface. logstash can push log from file with RFC log system format. You can use Logstash Forwarder for send log from logstash client to logstash server, too. but with log of applications that you want push to logstash server is very complex.
2. Scribe: i think that Scribe do not longer support by facebook. it is very old.
3. [Graylogs](http://graylog2.org) : Full stack for log central with interface, filter, input, ouput. we can push message log from any applications to API of graylog server very easy. but gray log can't read log from file :) .

Comment: Thank you, we are going to deploy Graylogs. We are almost satisfied  when looking at Graylogs' features.